# How to Convert Protobuf data into apache avro

Tags: java

I am using Apache Avro in my project and I have a requirement to save upcoming protobuf data in an Avro Schema. I searched in the internet but haven't found any solutions.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can not deserialize protobuf data by using the apache avro serialization system because they don't use the same **encoder/decoder protocol**.

One way to solve your problem is to create an interface system which deserializes the protobuf upcoming data (by using the protobuf system). After this step, you can easily fill your generated class with the data decrypted.

Comment: Thanks ... In my code we are currently used ProtobufDatamWriter to write protobuf data in avro schema but protobufDatamWriter not applicable to write its required protobuf generated class. please send me some code or give a way how to solved.

Comment: Try to use `DatumWriter<T>` from the Apache avro API (see more [here](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html#Serializing-N101DE)) with the protobuf data **deserialized**.

Answer (score 0):

I implement a conversion from protocol buffer to avro record
you could try it:
https://github.com/cecol/protobuf-to-avro
but you still need to provide proper protocol buffer schema .proto file and correspond avro .avsc file schema